# sed: replace letter between square brackets

Tags: sed

I have the following string:

```
signal[i]
signal[bg]
output [10:0]
input [i:1]
```

what I want is to replace the letters between square brackets (by underscore for example) and to keep the other strings that represents table declaration:

```
signal[_]
signal[__]
output [10:0]
input [i:1]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk '{gsub(/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/,"[_]")} 1'  Input_file
```

Globally substituting the (bracket)alphabets till their longest match then  with [_]. Mentioning 1 will print the lines(edited or without edited ones).

**EDIT:** Above will substitute all alphabets with one single _, so to get as many underscores as many characters are there following may help in same.

```
awk '{match($0,/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/);VAL=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);if(VAL){len=length(VAL);;while(i<len){q=q?q"_":"_";i++}};gsub(/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/,"["q"]")}1'   Input_file
```

**OR**

```
awk '{
        match($0,/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/);
        VAL=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);
        if(VAL){
                len=length(VAL);
                while(i<len){
                                q=q?q"_":"_";
                                i++
                            }
               };
        gsub(/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/,"["q"]")
     }
     1
    '   Input_file
```

Will add explanation soon.

**EDIT2:** Following is the one with explanation purposes for OP and users.

```
awk '{
        match($0,/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/);            #### using match awk's built-in utility to match the [alphabets] as per OP's requirement.
        VAL=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);    #### Creating a variable named VAL which has substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2); which will have substring value, whose starting point is RSTART+1 and ending point is RLENGTH-2.
                                                   RSTART and RLENGTH are the variables out of the box which will be having values only when awk finds any match while using match.
        if(VAL){                              #### Checking if value of VAL variable is NOT NULL. Then perform following actions.
                len=length(VAL);              #### creating a variable named len which will have length of variable VAL in it.
                while(i<len){                 #### Starting a while loop which will run till the value of VAL from i(null value).
                                q=q?q"_":"_"; #### creating a variable named q whose value will be concatenated it itself with "_".
                                i++           #### incrementing the value of variable i with 1 each time.
                            }
               };
        gsub(/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/,"["q"]")         #### Now globally substituting the value of [ alphabets ] with [ value of q(which have all underscores in it) then ].
     }
     1                                        #### Mentioning 1 will print (edited or non-edited) lines here.
    '  Input_file                             #### Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: thanks . this is solved my problem. I've also rectified my question to take into consideration when the letter is the size of the table.

Comment: @Kais: Sorry didn't get it, could you please do let me know your question, so that could try to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative ***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -F'\\[|\\]' '$2!~/^[0-9]+:[0-9]$/{ gsub(/./,"_",$2); $2="["$2"]" }1' OFS= file
```

The output:

```
signal[_]
signal[__]
output [10:0]
```

---

- `-F'\\[|\\]'` - treating `[` and `]` as field separators
- `$2!~/^[0-9]+:[0-9]$/` - performing action if the 2nd field does not *represent table declaration*
- `gsub(/./,"_",$2)` - replace each character with `_`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed ':a;s/\(\[_*\)[[:alpha:]]\([[:alpha:]]*\]\)/\1_\2/;ta' file
```

Match on opening and closing square brackets with any number of `_`'s and at least one alpha character and replace said character by an underscore and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{sub(/\[i\]/,"[_]")sub(/\[bg\]/,"[__]")}1' file

signal[_]
signal[__]
output [10:0]
input [i:1]
```

The explanation is as follows: Since bracket is as special character it has to be escaped to be handled literally then it becomes easy use sub.