# How do I find and replace multiple files with sed with Terminal in WHM?

Tags: sed

I have this string that I need to remove:

```
[0]);elem.appendAfter([0]);[0].appendChild(elem);})();
```

I was able to use find to remove javascript from all files, but I am unable to remove the code above from all files at once.

Here is what I have so far:

```
find . -name "*.json" -exec sed -i "s#[0]);elem.appendAfter([0]);[0].appendChild(elem);})();##g" {} \;
```

Comment: Your `[0]` is a reg-ex range expression composed of just the char `0`. The `[]` s stripped away by the reg-ex engine. Try `\[0\]`. If at all possible use the form `ssh user@xxx 'find ...'` to avoid other problems with parsing of `"` vs `'` chars. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed: replace letter between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259142/sed-replace-letter-between-square-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Shellter for the solution! This resolved the issue:

```
find . -name "*.json" -exec sed -i "s#\[0\]);elem.appendAfter(\[0\]);\[0\].appendChild(elem);})();##g" {} \;
```